# Coldfusion Password Protected RSS Feeds

Tags: coldfusion, rss, 37-signals

I'm interested in Password protecting my apps RSS Feeds. So when you load a RSS feed url in the browser the browser's default dialog asks for a login and password.

Any tutorials or tips on how to get this to securely work? 37 Signals has this behavior on their web apps.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mischefamily.com/nathan/index.cfm/2008/8/13/Basic-Authentication-With-ColdFusion

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it.  Most feed readers won't be able to consume your RSS feed if you put a password on it.  Most places utilize security of RSS by creating obscure hashes (a private ID) for an individual.  They can see this in their login, add the feed and viola.